# run a code every 5 minutes when django server is running

Tags: python, django

I have a django project and inside I have an app. Inside this app I created a management folder, inside this one I create a commands folder, and inside the last one I put my script with the init.py file too. My question is: how can I do to autorun that code every X minutes once the server is running to don't worry about execute the script myself.

Comment: Depends on your deployment environment, on pythonanywhere you can create a bash script that runs you command and schedule it. Openshift has it's own mechanism to schedule a task. Heroku may be the same. If you have your own server use crontab on linux and on windows task scheduler.

Comment: I have localhost at the moment, but I'm planning to put it in [here](https://c9.io/?redirect=0)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/django/5848/django-from-the-command-line/20597/django-as-a-cron-job#t=201611061141249666347

Comment: Then go for crontab as you're getting your own VM

Comment: Serjik, so if I go for crontab, how I have to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer, [django-chronograph](https://github.com/t11e/django-chronograph) is a simple application that allows you to control the frequency at which a Django management command gets run.

[chronograph](http://django-chronograph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html)

Hope this is helps you.

Comment: It was helpful, I did it like in the example that you pointed me. Thank you very much.